# Why my jsp page in Eclipse don't show the image into the img tag?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying to code a dynamic web project into Eclipse, but the tag img in the jsp page don't work. This is my project:

```
ProjectName
   --WebContent
        --WEB-INF
             --images
   page.jsp
```

And this is my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="Beans.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>HomePageImpiegato</title>
    <style>
        body{color: #333;font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;background-color: #F5F5F5;}
        h1{font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;font-size: 30px;color: #333;width: fit-content;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
        h4{font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;font-size: 20px;color: #333;width: fit-content;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
        .preventivi{height: fit-content;display: flex;width: 100%;}
        .preventiviGestiti{float: left;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 48%;}
        .preventiviLiberi{float: right;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;width: 48%;}
        .dati-personali{margin: auto;width: fit-content;}
        .gestisciPreventivo{margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: fit-content;margin-top: 50px;}
        #preventivi {font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;}
        #preventivi td, #preventivi th {border: 1px solid #ddd;padding: 8px;}
        #preventivi tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
        #preventivi tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
        #preventivi th {padding-top: 12px;padding-bottom: 12px;text-align: left;background-color: #4CAF50;color: white;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenuto">
    <h1>Home Page Impiegatodiv</h1>
    <%
        Utente utente = (Utente) session.getAttribute("utente");
        if (utente==null) {
            response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/LoginPage.html");
        }
        else {
            if (utente.getTipo().equals("cliente")) {
                response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/LoginPage.html");
            }
            else {
                %><div class="dati-personali"><%
                out.println("Ciao " + utente.getTipo() + " " + utente.getNome());
                out.println(" Con password " + utente.getPass());
                %></div><%
                Preventivo[] preventivi = (Preventivo[]) session.getAttribute("preventiviU");
                Preventivo[] preventiviNull = (Preventivo[]) session.getAttribute("preventiviN");
                %><div class="preventivi">
                    <div class="preventiviGestiti">
                    <h4>Preventivi gestiti in passato</h4>
                    <%
                    if (preventivi==null) {
                        out.println("Nessun preventivo");
                    }
                    else {
                    for (int i=0; i<preventivi.length; i++) {
                        %>
                        <table id="preventivi">
                            <tr>
                                <th><img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/WEB-INF/images/<%= preventivi[i].getImg() %>"></th>
                                <th><% out.println(preventivi[i].getId()); %></th>
                                <th><% out.println(preventivi[i].getCliente()); %></th>
                                <th><% out.println(preventivi[i].getImpiegato()); %></th>
                                <th><% out.println(preventivi[i].getPrezzo()); %></th>
                                <th><% out.println(preventivi[i].getNomeProdotto()); %></th>
                            </tr>
                        <%
                            Opzione[] opzioni = preventivi[i].getOpzioni();
                            for (int j=0; j<opzioni.length; j++) {%>
                            <tr>
                                <th><% out.println(opzioni[j].getNome()); %></th>
                                <th><% out.println(opzioni[j].getTipo()); %></th>
                            </tr>

                        <%
                            }
                        %></table><%
                    }
                %></div><%
                }
                %><div class="preventiviLiberi">
                    <h4>Preventivi da gestire</h4>
                <%
                    for (int i=0; i<preventiviNull.length; i++) {
                        %><table id="preventivi">
                            <tr>
                                <th><img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/WEB-INF/images/<%= preventiviNull[i].getImg() %>" height="42" width="42"></th>
                                <th><% out.println(preventiviNull[i].getId()); %></th>
                                <th><% out.println(preventiviNull[i].getCliente()); %></th>
                                <th><% out.println(preventiviNull[i].getImpiegato()); %></th>
                                <th><% out.println(preventiviNull[i].getPrezzo()); %></th>
                                <th><% out.println(preventiviNull[i].getNomeProdotto()); %></th>
                            </tr>
                            <%
                            Opzione[] opzioni = preventiviNull[i].getOpzioni();
                            for (int j=0; j<opzioni.length; j++) {%>
                            <tr>
                                <th><% out.println(opzioni[j].getNome()); %></th>
                                <th><% out.println(opzioni[j].getTipo()); %></th>
                            </tr>
                            <%
                            }
                        %></table><%
                    }
                    %></div><%
            %></div>    
        <div class="gestisciPreventivo">
            <h4>Gestisci preventivo</h4>
            <form action="gestisci" method="POST">
                    <select id="idPreventivoNew" name="idPreventivoNew">
                        <%
                            for (int i=0; i<preventiviNull.length; i++) {
                                %> <option value="<%= preventiviNull[i].getId() %>"> <%= preventiviNull[i].getId() %> </option> <%
                            }%>
                    </select>
                    <label>Scegli preventivo</label>
                    <input type="hidden" id="impiegato" name="impiegato" value="<%= utente.getNome() %>">
                    <input type="submit" value="PREZZA PREVENTIVO">
             </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <%
        }
    }
    %>
</body>
```

I also try to pass the absolute path but work only in Eclipse and not in the browser.
I also try to change my browser but i can't get any result.
Thanks

Comment: One thing's for sure: `WEB-INF` shouldn't be in the image path as it shouldn't be exposed like that by the application server.

Comment: no not place static resources such as images in `WEB-INF`. The contents of that folder are not accessible for http requests.